# Android Widget, Handling Button Clicks !

Tags: android, xml, widget, imagebutton

i'm having some ImageButtons on my widget and i'm handling them using my own action strings, none of them is a config. button .. i'm not having in my xml design an update period since i don't need to update anything, so all my handling is in the onReceive(context, intent) method!
but still wouldn't work .. i still don't really get the way we handle button clicks in widgets, can anyone help?? even with the core concept of handling buttons .. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the `onUpdate` method of your AppWidgetProvider:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmain);
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Call1.class);
configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageButton01, configPendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
```

Variables outside the method:

```
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ONE = 10;
```

In this code when you click on ImageButton01 of the widget, it launches Call1.class.

Comment: should i be having more that one object of type "RemoteViews", one for each button for example.. ?

Comment: Yes, you can, widget API have 3 overloading method to update view of widget, method appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,yourRemoteView) update view of widget have widgetID: appWidgetId.

Comment: You can use only one remoteViews for many intents, if you want.